# Boost HTTP Server Alternating 300ms delay in Chromium Browsers

Tags: c++, http, boost, server, boost-asio

I am using the example code for a simple Boost HTTP server and everything works fine but for Chromium based browsers the initial connection takes 300ms between every other request. For Firefox it behaves as expected.

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_82_0/libs/beast/example/http/server/small/http_server_small.cpp

[Chrome timing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltsRY.png)

[image]

[300ms initial connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd0CJ.png)

[image]

[FireFox all as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRG7U.png)

[image]

Is there a way to fix this and what is causing it?

Comment: Possibly [Nagle's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nagle%27s_algorithm).

Comment: What requests are you sending? I cannot reproduce this with either /count or /time (e.g. https://imgur.com/a/WNY07Rz)

Comment: @sehe if you open the browser console window: await fetch("/time", {method: "get"}).then((response) => {});

Comment: Same results for me: https://imgur.com/vPsvviY. Could a proxy be interfering?